# Remove slashes/parent paths from filenames inside CSS and Javascript content

Tags: shell, text-processing, find

I need to go through all my `css` and `js` files and if there is a filename referenced that has any slashes (`/`) at all then the slash should be removed.

What I want is:

- if any files referenced are named `/file.jpg` then remove the leading slash leaving just `file.jpg`.

  For example, in a CSS file change:

  `@import url("/base.css");` to `@import url("base.css");`
- if the file referenced is named `/files/file.jpg` then the leading slashes and folder name should be removed leaving just `file.jpg`.

I started to write it but then couldn't think about how to deal with the slashes.

```
grep -o -h -E '[A-Za-z0-9:./_-]+\.(png|jpg|gif|tif|css)' `find
${new_directory} -name '*.css' -or -name '*.js'`
```

Any idea how to do this? I am doing this using a `.sh` shell script.

Comment: ouch. that's nasty. I don't think I want to know how you ended up with that situation!  :-o

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/965053/extract-filename-and-extension-in-bash

Comment: Hmm...I think quite a few people have gotten the wrong end of the stick here. If I read this correctly, the question isn't about changing filenames on the filesystem, but filenames referenced in the CSS and javascript files themselves.

Answer (score 1):

Don't parse the output of `find` that way. It'll work if your files don't contain any special characters, but to invoke a command on the files found by `find`, it's easier and more robust to make `find` call the command:

```
find "$new_directory" -name '*.css' -o -name '*.js' -exec grep … {} +
```

Then `grep` isn't the right tool to perform a text replacement; it's only a search tool. `sed` is a stream editor, and its most widely used feature is regexp replacement. Assuming GNU sed (such as found on Linux), and assuming that your regexp is basically correct, i.e. that you want to match all sequences of letter-or-digit-or-`:._-` followed by a likely-looking extension as file names, here's a `sed` call to replace `DIR1/DIR2/FILE.EXT` by `FILE.EXT` everywhere:

```
sed -e 's![/A-Za-z0-9:._-]*/\([A-Za-z0-9:._-]*\.\(png\|jpg\|gif\|tif\|css\)\)!!g'
```

Putting both pieces together, if you want to make the replacements in place, the easiest way is to use GNU sed's `-i` option, which does just that.

```
find "$directory" -name '*.css' -o -name '*.js' \
     -exec sed -e 's![/A-Za-z0-9:._-]*/\([A-Za-z0-9:._-]*\.\(png\|jpg\|gif\|tif\|css\)\)!!g' {} +
```

If you want to put the replacements in a different place, you'll need a bit of intermediate shell glue to construct the names of the new files.

```
find "$old_directory" -name '*.css' -o -name '*.js' \
     -exec sh -c 'sed -e '\''s![/A-Za-z0-9:._-]*/\([A-Za-z0-9:._-]*\.\(png\|jpg\|gif\|tif\|css\)\)!!g'\' <"$0" >"/new/directory/$0"' {} \;
```

Note the use of `'\''` to put a single quote inside the single-quoted shell snippet. `-exec … {} \;` means to run the command once on each file, in contrast with `-exec … {} +` which runs the command on as many files in one batch as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `basename` built-in.  It works like this:

```
$ basename "/abc/def/ghi.jkl"
ghi.jkl
```